# Performance of WebFlux with retry exponential backoff

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-webflux, software-design

I'm building a webhook service that sends events to client's URLs.
In case of failure or timeout, I need to retry the sending with with exponential backoff. I've two ways to implement the logic:

1. Using WebClient's internal retry feature:

```
WebClient.create()
    .post()
    .uri(URL)
    .exchange()
    ...
    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(4, Duration.ofSeconds(3)).jitter(0.7));
```

2. Another way is using rabbitMQ `deadLetterExchange` to re-queue the message with exponential backoof as mentioned here:
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-exponential-backoff

Applying  WebFlux internal retry feature is easy for development but I've some concerns over using it because messages are stored in application memory and it may affect the performance when the number of messages are high.
I want to know other developers thoughts on these options.
Also, is there any better options?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion these two approaches can be used together.

The retry strategy is the simplest way to manage very transient error. BUT we cannot retry indefinitely.

An infinite retry may cause memory issue. But not only! When you shutdown a server, you probably wish to stop incoming traffic first and expect there is no computation/transaction during the shutting down ...

So we need another strategy for messages that failed after some retries. And a Dead Letter Queue is a valid option.

In the real life we may have several DQL, then the default one is used for the unexpected cases. Obviously we cannot hope to have a good algorithm in that cases.